# Processing external page with perl CGI or act as a reverse proxy

Tags: perl, apache, proxy, cgi

There is a page residing on a local server running Apache. I would like to submit the form via a GET request with a single name/value pair, like:

```
id=item1234
```

This GET request has to be processed by another server which I don't have control over subsequently returning a page which I would like to transform with the CGI script. In other words:

- User submits form
- MY apache proxies to external resource
- EXTERNAL resource throws back a page
- MY apache transforms it with a CGI (maybe another way?)
- User get a modified page

Again this more like an architectural question so I'd be grateful for any hints, even poking my nose into some guides will help as I wasn't able to structure my google request well enough to locate anything related.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you did not ask a question? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the id "17929632" to this CGI code ("proxy.pl?id=17929632"), and you should this exact page in your browser.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use CGI::Pretty qw(:standard -any -no_xhtml -oldstyle_urls);
print header;
print "<html>\n";
print "  <head><title>Proxy Demo</title></head>\n";
print "  <body bgcolor=\"white\">\n";

my $id = param('id') || die "No CGI param 'id'\n";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");

# Create a request
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/$id");

# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $response = $ua->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ($response->is_success) {
  my $content = $response->content;
  # Modify the original content here!
  print $content;
}
else {
  print $response->status_line;
}

print "</body></html>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Vague question, vague answer: write your CGI program to include a HTTP user agent, e.g. [LWP](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent).